# Gitlab CI / CD pipeline of infra as code with DevSecOps

Tags: gitlab, yaml, aws-cloudformation, gitlab-ci

I am working on an AWS cloud infra as code project, we are using CloudFormation and we want to create a CI / CD pipeline to manage the code.

One of the principles of our organization is the semantic versioning that ideally should be applied to all version control. In addition, I would like to set a security test mode in the "SEC" of DevSecOps.

For this, I already checked the Scout Suite tool (container) and the Cloud Conformity (pre-commit in VS Code). I would like to use other tools for the CloudFormation security test and also for a Compliance as Code model.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure to explicitely state what your question is. (s. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Last year AWS released a tool that is now GA just for this [cloudformation-guard](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-guard)

You can write policy as code to test AWS Cloudformation for compliance.